# Dell UltraSharp U3219Q - Apple MacBook M1 Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, display, usb

I have a 2021 Apple MacBook M1 Pro Max connected via a USB-C cable to Dell UltraSharp U3219Q.

When I restart my Macbook, the Dell screen is not recognised and I have to power off the screen, disconnect the USB cable, login to my laptop and then reconnect the cable for it to be recognised.

Is this a common behaviour or is anyone else experiencing this issue?

Comment: Is it USB-C or USB-C with Thunderbolt? The USB-C connector can be USB 3.1 only, Power only, and Thunderbolt (among others...) Also some Dell monitors have *directional* ports so you plug the cable from the Mac to the "IN" port and a downstream device (another monitor, a hub, etc) into the "OUT" port

Comment: The cable is Thunderbolt 4 Cable 2m/40Gbps,Maxonar TB4 USB C4.0 Cable 20V/5A 100W Supports 8K30hz/5K@60Hz or Dual 4K60hz Monitor. I specifically bought this cable as it supports data, power, display and everything else.

Comment: For some reason, I have to remove the Dell screen power cable for it to recognise the USB-C connection